# Form validation with Ajax call triggers when not validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-5

I have a simple form with Ajax call, but ajax call gets executed even if form is not validated.

In below code line `console.log("This line should execute only if Form is validated");` gets executed when form is not validate.

Bootstrap 5 validation  [Codepen code](https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/zYZMWrO?editors=1111)

```
    (function () {
      "use strict";
      const forms = document.querySelectorAll(".requires-validation");
      Array.from(forms).forEach(function (form) {
        form.addEventListener(
          "submit",
          function (event) {
            if (!form.checkValidity()) {
              event.preventDefault();
              event.stopPropagation();
            }
 else
            {
            console.log("This line should execute only if Form is validated");
            // Call Ajax Function
            // AjaxCallSaveData();
}
            form.classList.add("was-validated");
          },
          false
        );
      });
    })();
    
    //$(document).ready(function () {
    function AjaxCallSaveData() 
    {
      $("form").submit(function (event) {
        var formData = {
          name: $("#name").val(),
          email: $("#email").val(),
          message: $("#message").val(),
          superheroAlias: $("#superheroAlias").val()
        };
    
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "SubmitFORM.php",
          data: formData,
          dataType: "json",
          encode: true
        }).done(function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        });
    
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
    //});
```

Not sure if i am doing it right?

HTML

```
<div class="form-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-holder">
      <div class="form-content">
        <div class="form-items">
          <h3>Register you interest</h3>
          <p>Fill in the data below, we will get back to you!</p>
          <form class="requires-validation" action="SubmitFORM.php" method="POST" novalidate>

            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
              <div class="valid-feedback">Username field is valid!</div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">Username field cannot be blank!</div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
              <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail Address" required>
              <div class="valid-feedback">Email field is valid!</div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">Email field cannot be blank!</div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
              <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
            </div>


            <div class="form-button mt-3">
              <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()` will not prevent next line of code to execute. To do that, you should use return statement.

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc, what confuses me is that similar code runs fine in this example..https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/poeQaqZ console message only show when form is validated

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc, i noticed that when i remove `novalidate` from Form tag console message show only when forms is validated.

Comment: Add return just break the validation and submits the form

Comment: If you remove `novalidate`, the code doesn't even run the function attached to submit event when from is invalid because `required` or `type="email"` will prevent form from submiting if it's invalid

Answer (score 0):

`event.preventDefault()` will only stop the form from submitting. It cannot stop next lines of the JavaScript function from executing.

You should use `return` in place of `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: what confuses me is that similar code runs fine in this example..https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/poeQaqZ console message only show when form is validated

Comment: i noticed that when i remove novalidate from Form tag console message show only when forms is validated and for this reason second example works fine moment we add custom error message it doesnt work as intended

Comment: @Learning You will have the same issue in this example as well. The AJAX request will send regardless of the input being correct or wrong. However, the form will not ```submit``` unless the values are correct.

Comment: @Learning  You are confusing ```AJAX POST request``` with normal form ```POST```.

Comment: I tried, its not working for.. I simply want to submit form through Ajax call when client side validation is successful... i would apprecite is you can share the you think will work

Comment: I am bit confused as i have not done something similar on bootstrap 5 validation.. there are lots of example for Ajax with third party validation libraries and for Bootstrap 4.x but not much for bootstrap 5..

Comment: This works when `novalidate` is removed from forms if i add it back form doesnt show validation message or change the border to Green when validate..

Comment: Why would you need novalidate? I actually have never used it so I can't say how it effects your code.